# Having a hard time with wx.Config

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, python-2.7, configuration-files

My problem is that I wanna make a config file for an application but things aren't as simple as they seamed. So I've seen a tutorial where a config file contained the width and the height and the values that followed the equal sign could been retrieved and used to establish the size of a frame. Been there, done that, and everything worked okey. Strangely enough this seams to work only for some key words, as if I've used in the config file, also a parameter named freq it didn't retrieved its value as it did with the width, height parameters.

for example if I have a piece of code like this:

```
   self.cfg = wx.Config('myconf')
   wid = self.cfg.ReadInt('width')
   hei = self.cfg.ReadInt('height')
   freq = self.cfg.ReadInt('frequency')
   print wid, hei, freq
```

where in myconf

```
   width=400
   height=250
   frequency=3000
```

So it displays the height, the width but not the frequency, as for freq it gives only 0, and this happens for any other word I use in the config file. I'm guessing that only certain key words can be used in the config file, so they could be recognized while using wxPython.

If so where could I get a list of those keys I could use in making a configuration file ?

Comment: wanna is not a real word, it's slang. It should be "I want to make...."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I would recommend using [ConfigParser](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/ConfigParser/) which comes with Python or perhaps [ConfigObj](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/01/01/a-brief-configobj-tutorial/) (which I like better). If you're trying to save widget attributes / settings, then you also might want to look at the [PersistenManager](http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/Phoenix/lib.agw.persist.persistencemanager.PersistenceManager.html)

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot man. ConfigParser is exactly what I've needed, and hopped to achieve with wx.Config. Especially because you can also organize your config file in sections. I don't know what's wrong with wx.Config, but it seams it doesn't works all the time. For me anyway.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is reading the lines yourself:

```
F = open('myconf', 'r')
for line in F.read().split('\n'):
    switchres = { 'frequency': print(line.split('=')[1]),
                            # add the rest
                            }
    switchres[line.split('=')[0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

wxPython is a wrapper (or binding) for wxWidgets that is a C++ library.

So wx.Config or wx.FileConfig is intended for C++ that has no specific way of treating these type of config file (still wx.Config is meant to be portable between platforms).

In Python you already have ConfigParser module, but have in mind:

- that some wxPython classes work with wx.Config like wx.FileHistory,
- use wx.Config if you want to use the platform specific way of storing configurations (like registry in Windows).